# Function as the first argument of .then()

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

Why do we have to write `function() {/*call some other function*/}` or `() => {}` inside `.then()` in promise?

Let's say for example that we have one promise

```
someFn = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve("Resolved");
    }, 2000);
  })
}
```

And we also have random function

```
anotherFn = () => {
    console.log("in time");
}
```

To chain those functions we will use `.then()`

```
someFn().then(success => console.log(success)).then(() => anotherFn());
```

My question is, why is `anotherFn()` executed immediately if I write it like this `.then(anotherFn())` and it waits with execution if it has `() => {}`?

As far as I know, the first argument that `.then()` takes is `onFulfilled` which is a function, and `anotherFn()` is also a function.

Comment: `.then(anotherFn)` should work just fine.

Comment: By doing `anotherFn()` you have requested execution of the function here itself

Comment: `anotherFn() is also a function.` ... no ... `anotherFn()` is the result of calling `anotherFn`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapping your function in `() => {...}` is creating a new anonymous function that is waiting to be invoked.

By writing `.then(anotherFunction())` you are invoking the function immediately upon being read. In your example as `anotherFunction` does not have a return value this would be equivalent to `.then(undefined)`.

Step by step, what happens here is your code launches your async request, then continues to read ahead. In the `then` block it sees a function which is invoked immediately, the `console.log` runs returning `undefined`. Eventually the promise resolves and `.then(undefined)` is called.

Passing an invoked function to `.then` might be useful if `anotherFunction` was curried and returned from it a new function that should be executed on completion.

To make this work in the desired way you just need to just pass the function to the `then` block without invoking it (rather than passing it the return value of the function by invoking it).

`.then(anotherFunction)`

Here `anotherFunction` will be invoked with the return value from the promise only once it has resolved.